# Shield with or shield by?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, by-with

In the sentence like: she shielded herself from disquiet **by** mocking arrogance.

What's correct? *By* or *with*? Is there any difference if they both are acceptable?

Comment: That's an interesting example. Simplistically, use *with* with noun phrases and *by* with verb phrases: e.g. *she shielded herself from arrows with a door / by closing the door*. However, your example seems to work (taking *mocking arrogance* to be a noun phrase denoting a type of arrogance, as opposed to a verb phrase that indicates what she was mocking). I think *by* allows both NP/VP interpretations (and seems more 'literary' with the NP interpretation) while *with* allows only the *NP* interpretation.

Comment: Wow, Lawrence; I wish I'd noticed that long ago. Thanks.